# Redirect after PUT or GET method in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

views.py

```
class Update(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Main.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MainSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

I want to redirect url after update or delete my article To '/api/.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) for redirecting to the desired URL after updating or deleting the article.

Here's an example:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class Update(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Main.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MainSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return redirect('/api/')

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().patch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return redirect('/api/')
```

You'll need to adjust the URL of `redirect` function accordingly.

Comment: unfortunately, your solution not worked. If you want to see the whole project you can access to them from this link: [link](https://github.com/mohamadhasan-zeinali/django-blog-dashboard)

Comment: @mohamadhasanzeinali Can you provide more details in the question? Or is it giving you some error?

Comment: I try to solve that like your solution you're mentioned. But not worked. Redirect not worked just did update or deleted.

Comment: @mohamadhasanzeinali Verify that the URL you are redirecting to is correct. If the URL is incorrect, the redirect will fail. You can also try using a different URL to see if the redirect works.